# ¿Qué función cumple el siguiente código? Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
numeros = [-1.4, 2.3, 5.27, -3.5, 2.9, 3.12]
lista = [(x > 0) - (x < 0) for x in numeros]
print(lista)
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
```

La duda es qué función cumple `(x > 0) - (x < 0)` y cómo podría interpretarlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Básicamente devuelve el signo del número

Comment: Es una forma de evitar el `if` tal vez con el sentido que sea más performante, con éste, sería: lista = `[1 if (x > 0) else -1 for x in numeros]`

Comment: Me desdigo del tema performance, al menos en Python3 el operador ternario es más rápido. ¿Podrías dar mayor contexto a tu pregunta? ¿Que versión de python?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¿Y porqué automáticamente se le asigna "1" o "-1" y no cualquier otro número y su negativo?

Comment: Por coerción, tanto `(x > 0)` como  `(x > 0)` retornan un booleano (`True` o `False`, la resta coerciona ambos retornos a un numérico `1-0` o `0-1`

Comment: Había deducido que actuaban como True o False pero no tenía ni idea de que python los convertía a unos y ceros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si `x` es positivo, entonces `(x>0)` será `True` mientras que `(x<0)` será `False`, por lo que `(x>0)-(x<0)` será evaluado como `True - False`. Ya que los booleanos no pueden restarse, Python los tratará como `1 - 0` y el resultado será `1`.

Si `x` es negativo, de forma análoga puedes ver que el resultado será `-1`

Y **aún queda otro caso**. Si `x` es cero, entonces tanto `(x>0)` como `(x<0)` son falsos, por lo que el resultado en este caso será `0`.

Asi pues toda esa expresión se comporta como una especie de [función signo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_signo), que python no trae implementada de serie (aunque [numpy sí la implementa](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html))

Lo mismo mediante un operador ternario sería `-1 if x<0 else 1 if x>0 else 0`. Personalmente creo que éste es más claro, y probablemente hasta más eficiente.